# PHP Problems (file uploading)

Tags: php, file-upload, web

I have been working on a website for some time now, and the code I used here worked about a month ago, then I tried putting the file in a subfolder, and redirecting the move_uploaded_file function, but it doesn't seem to be working. To be specific, both the:

```
if((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_letter"])) &&  ($_FILES['uploaded_letter']['error'] == 0))
```

and

```
if((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_list"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_list']['error'] == 0))
```

statements are returning false.
If anyone could please help with that, that would be awesome! Thanks!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>VAA Chapter 11</title>
        <!--favicon-->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />

        <!--global CSS-->
        <link href="vaa.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!--local CSS-->
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        function testPassword(){
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            if($password == 'You aint guessin this'){
                echo 'welcome!!! <br/>
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" /> <br/>
                        add newsletter: <input name="uploaded_letter" type="file" /><br/><br/>
                        add list: <input name="uploaded_list" type="file" /><br/><br/>
                        <input type="submit" name="load" value="Upload" />
                </form>';
            }
            else{
                echo "you have no power here";
            }
         }
        function upload(){
            if((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_letter"])) &&  ($_FILES['uploaded_letter']['error'] == 0)) {
                $filename = basename($_FILES['uploaded_letter']['name']);
                $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

                if (($ext == "pdf") && ($_FILES["uploaded_letter"]["size"] < 35000000)) {
                    $newname = dirname(__FILE__,1).'/newsletters/'.$filename;

                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_letter']['tmp_name'],$newname);
                } 
                else {
                    echo "Error: file is too large";
                }
            } 
            else {
                echo "Error: No file uploaded";
            }
            if((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_list"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_list']['error'] == 0)) {
                $filename = basename($_FILES['uploaded_list']['name']);
                $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

                if (($ext == "txt") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 35000)) {
                    $newname = dirname(__FILE__,1).'/'.$filename;

                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_list']['tmp_name'],$newname);
                } 
                else {
                    echo "Error: file is too large";
                }
            } 
            else {
                echo "Error: No file uploaded";
            }
        }
        function testUpload(){
            if(isset($_POST['load'])){
                upload();
            }
        }
        ?>    
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="password" />
            <input type="submit" value="OK" />  
        </form>
        <?php testPassword(); testUpload(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the error logs? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Yup, nothing. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Not working **HOW**?

Comment: Have you checked permissions on the directory you are uploading to?

Comment: Yes, I have checked permissions, and, for Marc I have been more specific in my question.

Answer (score 0):

it is better if you have more than one file to upload to use array for naming your file foe example `add newsletter: <input name="uploaded_letter[]" type="file" />` 
`add list: <input name="uploaded_letter[]" type="file" />`then you can use foreach  in target page

Comment: did he say/wrote any multiple file upload here ??

Comment: Cool! Thanks! I'll try that.

Comment: And yes, he is seeing that there are two different file inputs in my code.

Comment: you can validate each file before uploading , so you can keep them in one name as array

Comment: Yes, there is two different file. Agree. But, those file are for different reason. One for news letter and other for some list. @ZachThePilot

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
if((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_letter"]["name"]))
{
    // Your Procedures
}

if((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_list"]["name"]))
{
  // Your Procedures
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use if and else if conditions properly in upload() like:

```
function upload(){
        if((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_letter"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_letter']['error'] == 0)) {
            //your code......
        }
        //missing elseif statement instead of if

        elseif ((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_list"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_list']['error'] == 0)) {
            //your code....

      else {
                echo "Error: file is too large";
            }
        } 
        else {
            echo "Error: No file uploaded";
        }
    }
```